# LINQ vs DLINQ: Advantages and Disadvantages

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, linq, linq-to-sql

To start off, I know DLINQ (LINQ-to-SQL) uses LINQ as base. In addition I know that Microsoft has stopped/paused further development on DLINQ, but still fully support it in new versions of the .NET framework.

What I am wondering is what advantages and disadvantages there is between the two.

Is there something that you can do in LINQ that is not possible in DLINQ?

Or does DLINQ cover all aspects of LINQ?

Comment: They are 2 different things, I think.  Linq to SQL is an ORM while Linq is a query language.

Comment: @user1477388 So DLINQ would be a "bridge" between LINQ and SQL?

Comment: Linq to SQL is an ORM.  Look up ORM.  They are basically an abstraction so you don't have to write SQL code, you can just write LINQ which is easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like someone mentioned in the comments, LINQ is a query language while DLINQ (or LINQ to SQL) is an ORM for interacting with the database. LINQ to SQL uses LINQ to select data from the database, but they are really two different things. This question is similar to comparing SQL to mySQL.

LINQ itself is not going anywhere. It's used for LINQ to SQL, EntityFramework, and several other ORMs. It's also used for LINQ to XML (query structured XML data) and LINQ to Objects (query IEnumerables in memory).

LINQ to SQL is still functional, but MS is encouraging people toward using EntityFramework instead so you should consider that for any new development

Comment: OK, that cleared up a lot of confusion that the internet gave when researching. Thanks